# Problem using INNER JOIN, returning unexpected values

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I'm facing a problem using INNER JOIN and would like some help from the community.

I have this 2 tables:

Table 1

| member_id | cod_id | compl_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Z-100 | 149 | A42 |
| Z-100 | 153 | B42 |

Table 2:

| member_id | cod_id | compl_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Z-100 | 149 | A42 |
| Z-100 | 153 | B42 |
| Z-100 | 187 | D03 |

My query:

```
SELECT t1.member_id, t2.cod_id, t2.compl_id
FROM Table_1 t1
INNER JOIN Table_2 t2
    ON t2.member_id = t1.member_id
      AND t2.cod_id <> t1.cod_id
      AND t2.compl_id <> t1.compl_id
```

Result obtained:

| member_id | cod_id | compl_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Z-100 | 149 | A42 |
| Z-100 | 153 | B42 |
| Z-100 | 187 | D03 |
| Z-100 | 187 | D03 |

Expected result:

| member_id | cod_id | compl_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Z-100 | 187 | D03 |

I already understand what is happening here for these values to be returned, but I'm not sure how to get around the situation.

Comment: It seems you are after a `NOT EXISTS`, not a `JOIN`.

Comment: yes, I have tried using NOT EXISTS but I had the exactly same result. I can't find where I'm going wrong.

Comment: [Edit] your question to demonstrate your `NOT EXISTS` attempt.

Answer (score 4):

You just can use [**`EXCEPT`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) set operator such as

```sql
SELECT * FROM table2 EXCEPT SELECT * FROM table1
```

but if you need full-difference between two tables, then combine the results such as

```sql
(SELECT * FROM table2 EXCEPT SELECT * FROM table1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM table1 EXCEPT SELECT * FROM table2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below Query using Where after the join and the "NOT IN" Subquery

```
SELECT t1.member_id, t2.cod_id, t2.compl_id
FROM Table_1 t1
INNER JOIN Table_2 t2
ON t2.member_id = t1.member_id
  Where t2.cod_id NOT IN (select cod_id from Table_1)
  AND t2.compl_id NOT IN (select compl_id from Table_1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done it with just a LEFT JOIN, see the last SELECT after the example setup. This is dependant on knowing that table 2 is the driving table, so won't work the other way around.

[image]

BUT I do like the EXCEPT approach :)

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT  * FROM tempdb.dbo.sysobjects O WHERE O.xtype in ('U') AND O.id = object_id(N'tempdb..#Table1'))
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Removing temp table #Table1'
    DROP TABLE #Table1;
END

CREATE TABLE #Table1 (
    member_id VARCHAR(10),
    cod_id INT,
    compl_id varchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO #Table1(member_id, cod_id, compl_id) 
VALUES 
('Z-100', 149, 'A42'),
('Z-100', 153, 'B42');

IF EXISTS (SELECT  * FROM tempdb.dbo.sysobjects O WHERE O.xtype in ('U') AND O.id = object_id(N'tempdb..#Table2'))
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Removing temp table #Table2'
    DROP TABLE #Table2;
END

CREATE TABLE #Table2 (
    member_id VARCHAR(10),
    cod_id INT,
    compl_id varchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO #Table2(member_id, cod_id, compl_id) 
VALUES 
('Z-100', 149, 'A42'),
('Z-100', 153, 'B42'),
('Z-100', 187, 'D03');

SELECT T2.*
FROM #Table2 AS T2
LEFT JOIN #Table1 AS T1 ON T1.member_id = T2.member_id AND T1.compl_id = T2.compl_id AND T1.cod_id = T2.cod_id
WHERE T1.member_id IS NULL
```